# NServiceBus updating from V4 to V5, Configure.Instance

Tags: c#, nservicebus, nservicebus5

we are updating from V4 to V5. In V4 we used instance of configure, but right now it's not possible.
this is my code

```
Configure.Instance.Builder.Build(handlerType)
NServiceBus.Configure.Instance.Builder.Build<IBus>()
```

Is there anybody who knows anything about how to get an instance of configure in NServiceBus

Comment: Why do you need the Configure instance? The whole static class is now obsolete.

Comment: Why do you need to statically access the IBus? – Furthermore why do you build up the handler type yourself? Handler creation is done by NServiceBus itself.
Can you elaborate a bit more your scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing the builder over the static property is no longer supported in V5. Starting from V4 `Configure` is instance based and no longer static. You
have the following possibilities:

- Create a static container accessor and access your container directly
- Create a bootstrapping class which implements `IWantToRunBeforeConfigurationIsFinalized` and access `Configure` there

`public class MyBootstrapper : IWantToRunBeforeConfigurationIsFinalized { 
      public void Run(Configure config) { 
         config.Builder.Build<YourDependency>(); 
   } 
}`

Comment: The Builder is a property of the UnicastBus class and another option would be to case IStartableBus instance to UnicastBus but this would be a bit dirty.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev that might be deprecated in the future. I wouldn't advice to do that.